# UIButton and UIControlEventState issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button

I'm having a very specific "bug" in my iPhone application. I'm setting two images for the highlighted and normal states of a button. It works as expected when you "press" and then "touch up" at a slow pace, but if you click/tap it quickly, there's a noticeable flicker between states. Is this a known bug or am I setting the states incorrectly?

Here's the code that creates the buttons:

```
UIImage *normalImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-small.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0f topCapHeight:0.0f];
UIImage *highlightedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-small-down.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0f topCapHeight:0.0f];

[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[self setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:FALSE];
[self setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:FALSE];
```

When a button is tapped it simply disables itself and enables the other button:

```
- (IBAction)aboutButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    aboutButton.enabled = FALSE;
    rulesButton.enabled = TRUE;
}

- (IBAction)rulesButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    rulesButton.enabled = FALSE;
    aboutButton.enabled = TRUE;
}
```

Any thoughts on this quick-click flicker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I resolved this. Took a bit of reverse engineering what I was trying to do, but I thought I'd post what I did in case it helps someone else.

The first thing I did was modify the aboutButtonTouched method to log the button's state property which is a bit-mask NSUInteger:

```
- (IBAction)aboutButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    rulesButton.enabled = TRUE;
    [sender setEnabled:FALSE];    

    NSLog(@"%d", [sender state]);
}
```

At this point, the button is disabled through setEnabled, and the log reported that the state was "3". Looking at the bit-mask type for UIControlState:

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,            // 0
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,       // 1
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,       // 2
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,       // 4
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

(Notes added since I can never remember bitwise). We can see that to get "3" (0011) we should use `UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateDisabled` (0001|0010 or 1|2), something which I did not have as a state in my original button definition. The key here that there's a brief time when the state is both before just being disabled ("A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and and when there is a touch up" -- from the docs). So the final state settings for the button where it does not flicker are:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: I don't know why; but in my testing on iOS5 it's not "3" but "5". Which is "UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted"

Comment: @HansPinckaers If they added new items to the bitmask, the values could have changed.

Comment: Well, i just subclassed UIButton and added a method to set state 1 to 5. No more flickering :)

Answer (score 1):

To be noted that, although not documented, all state combinations that contain `UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateDisabled` aren't valid: these are equivalent to same without `UIControlStateDisabled`.

In short:

`(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateDisabled) == UIControlStateHighlighted`

and

`(UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateDisabled) == (UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)`

I found that the hard way: was setting some attributes for the Highlighted+Disabled state which was overwriting my settings for the Highlighted state. Spent half a day to track down the issue why button wasn't properly highlighting...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reverse the sequence of changing the buttons

```
- (IBAction)aboutButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    rulesButton.enabled = TRUE;
    aboutButton.enabled = FALSE;
}
```

When you hide the one button first and then show the other, there's maybe a little gap, which creates the flicker. I think it's better to show the other button first.